# Weights of universal enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semi simple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field $F$ with

1. Cartan decomposition $L = h \oplus n_+ \oplus n_- $,
2. Root system $\Phi$,
3. Set of positive roots $\Phi_+$,
4. Simple roots $\Delta$.

Consider the universal enveloping algebra $U(n_+)$ of $n_+$ which can be consider as a $n_+$ - module.

What is the dimension of the weight space $U(n_+)_\beta$ for a root $\beta$ ?

I am trying to prove that, this dimension is equal to $K(\beta,q)$ where $K(.;q)$ is the q-kostant partition function.

$K(\beta,q)$ = co-efficient of $e^{-\beta}$ in the product $\prod_{\alpha \in \Phi_+}(1-qe^{-\alpha})^{-mult   \alpha}$

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How can the dimension depend on $q $ which does not appear elsewhere?

Comment: I think, I should consider Kostant partition $K(\beta)$ function instead of q-Kostant partition function, in which has we can just forget $q$ everywhere in the problem. is it okay now? thanks.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on how you make this an $L $-module?

Comment: Sorry. $U_{n_+}$ as $n_+$ module. I will correct it in the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You need to also have the Cartan acting to speak about weights.

Comment: Cartan acts on $n_+$ by adjoint (ie.just by Lie bracket). we can extent this action to whole $U(n_+)$ by PBW thm. This is what I have understand about this action.

Comment: Please ask if you want any more information. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting ${\mathscr S}(V)$ the symmetric algebra over a vector space $V$, realized as the subalgebra of symmetric tensors within the tensor algebra ${\mathscr T}(V)$ (as opposed to a quotient), the PBW-Theorem implies that $$\bigotimes\limits_{\alpha\in\Phi_+} {\mathscr S}({\mathfrak g}_{\alpha})\to\bigotimes\limits_{\alpha\in\Phi_+}{\mathscr U}({\mathfrak n}_+)\xrightarrow{\text{mult}}{\mathscr U}({\mathfrak n}_+)$$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, which moreover is quickly seen to be ${\mathfrak h}$-linear. Hence, 
$$\chi\left({\mathscr U}({\mathfrak n}_+)\right) = \prod\limits_{\alpha\in\Phi_+}\chi\left({\mathscr S}({\mathfrak g}_{\alpha})\right).\quad\quad(\ddagger)$$
Similarly, denoting ${\mathbb C}_\alpha$ the simple ${\mathfrak h}$-module with weight $\alpha$, we have ${\mathscr S}({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)\cong {\mathscr S}({\mathbb C}_\alpha)^{\otimes \dim({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)}$, so $$\chi\left({\mathscr S}({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)\right)=\chi\left({\mathscr S}({\mathbb C}_\alpha)\right)^{\dim({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)}=(1+e^{\alpha} + e^{2\alpha} + ...)^{\dim({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)}=(1-e^{-\alpha})^{-\dim({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)},$$
which together with $(\ddagger)$ gives your claim, up to the $q$ of which I also don't know what it's supposed to be.

Comment: In the first expression, you mean just $U(n_+)$ I think, instead of tensoring over it. am I correct or not. Thanks.

Comment: First, each ${\mathscr S}({\mathfrak g}_\alpha)$ naturally maps to ${\mathscr U}({\mathfrak n}_+)$, and then I apply the multiplication map.

Comment: Please explain what is a simple $h$ module $ \mathbb{C}_\alpha$ with weight $\alpha$. Thanks.

Comment: It's the $1$-dimensional ${\mathfrak h}$-module on which ${\mathfrak h}$ acts by $\alpha$.

Comment: thanks. nice. I have understand. please clarify this, in the line in which you have written the isomorphism, it is symmetric algebra of tensor product of $\mathbb{C}_\alpha$ or tensor product of symmetric algebra of $\mathbb{C}_\alpha$? thanks.

Comment: Tensor product of copies of the symmetric algebra over ${\mathbb C}_\alpha$.

Comment: thanks. very nice answer. can you suggest me any reference please?

Comment: The statement itself is mentioned and used in Humphrey's book on semisimple Lie algebras, but I don't think much is said about the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and clarifications.

Comment: @GA316 Note that this also directly gives the alternative description of the Kostant partition function, which is the number of ways to write $\beta$ as a sum of positive roots.